# Auth in CakePhp using 2 tables

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, acl

I would like to know how to make a login in CakePhp when my data comes from 2 tables.
Due to the specifications in the application the data in the table is divided like this:
users:                             details:
id                                 id
idDetail                           username
group_id                           password

While doing the login from the users_controller, I would like to make the Auth component to check the username and password from the view against the details table. Is there such a way to do this login mechanism without doing it from the details_controller? or a way to login from details_controller and making the ACL to check the users table to grant access?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. Create a model which is linked to the DB view. Basically it will be an empty model like:

```
class UserView extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'UserView';
}
```

now in your AppController's beforeFilter action use

```
$this->Auth->userModel = 'UserView';
```

And this should do the job. Take a look on this article in [the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/248/AuthComponent-Variables)

Comment: I'm just wondering whether you still use the UsersController and if so do you need to loadModel the User model?

Comment: @firith: are the two tables related?

Comment: Yes, they were related. I had to override the Auth::identify component to get this working, thanks a lot :)